# How can I make the child element change when hover is applied on the parent?

Tags: html, css, hover, parent-child

How can I make the child element change when hover is applied on the parent ?
I want to make the icon inside the box scale whenever I hover the box with the image. I would like to keep these same effects but when I hover the box everything is affected. 
Thank you!

```css
.box {
  display: inline-block !important;
  position: relative !important;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: rgba(50, 58, 70, .3);

}
.box-overlay {
  position: absolute;
  transition: background 0.2s ease, padding 0.8s linear;
  background-color: rgba(50, 58, 70, .6);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.box-overlay > span {
 display: none; 
 
}
.box-overlay:hover  > span {
 display: inline; 
 
}
.box a:hover .box-overlay {
  display: inline;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  transition: background 0.2s ease, padding 0.8s linear;
  background-color: rgba(50, 58, 70, .3);
  color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.box-overlay span {
 transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.box-overlay span {
  position: relative;
  top: 38%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
.go img{
 -webkit-transition: all .3s ease; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -moz-transition: all .3s ease; /* Firefox */
    -ms-transition: all .3s ease; /* IE 9 */
    -o-transition: all .3s ease; /* Opera */
    transition: all .3s ease;
}
.go img:hover {
  -webkit-transform:scale(1.25); /* Safari and Chrome */
    -moz-transform:scale(1.25); /* Firefox */
    -ms-transform:scale(1.25); /* IE 9 */
    -o-transform:scale(1.25); /* Opera */
     transform:scale(1.25);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <a href="#">
        <div class="box-overlay">
          <span class="go">
   <img src="img/go.svg" width="50px" height="50px">
    </span>
        </div>
    <img src="img/aa-family-car.jpg" alt="" height="300" width="300" class="responsive">
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How can I make the child element change when hover is applied on the parent ? I want to make the icon inside the box scale whenever I hover the box with the image.

The parent of the "icon" is the span so this

```
.go img:hover {
     -webkit-transform:scale(1.25); /* Safari and Chrome */
    -moz-transform:scale(1.25); /* Firefox */
    -ms-transform:scale(1.25); /* IE 9 */
    -o-transform:scale(1.25); /* Opera */
     transform:scale(1.25);
}
```

should be this

```
.go:hover img {
     -webkit-transform:scale(1.25); /* Safari and Chrome */
    -moz-transform:scale(1.25); /* Firefox */
    -ms-transform:scale(1.25); /* IE 9 */
    -o-transform:scale(1.25); /* Opera */
     transform:scale(1.25);
}
```

If you mean that the icon should scale when you hover over the *whole thing* then

```
.box:hover .go img {
         -webkit-transform:scale(1.25); /* Safari and Chrome */
        -moz-transform:scale(1.25); /* Firefox */
        -ms-transform:scale(1.25); /* IE 9 */
        -o-transform:scale(1.25); /* Opera */
         transform:scale(1.25);
    }
```

I've simplified the final version code a little in this [**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/evaudsfv/2/)

Comment: Thank you sir! On the fiddle the background does not change it's opacity whenever I hover though.